# I cannot open the webcam in p5.js

Tags: webcam, p5.js

In `p5js` editor, I wanted to test the example called `capture` to turn on my webcam on my mac pro.
The code must be correct since I used the example that already existed, but the camera is not turning on and I do not know why.

the console says:

{
"constraintName": "",
"message": "",
"name": "InvalidStateError"
}

```js
let capture;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(390, 240);
  capture = createCapture(VIDEO);
  capture.size(320, 240);
  //capture.hide();
}

function draw() {
  background(255);
  image(capture, 0, 0, 320, 240);
  filter(INVERT);
}
```

Comment: What browser are you using? I can run this code from FireFox and Chrome by clicking to allow the web cam. Have you tried running this code from here https://p5js.org/examples/dom-video-capture.html

Comment: Yes! It works on the web editor, but not on the editor that I download on my computer.

Comment: What editor are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Using the P5.js webcam feature requires the user to click "allow" before allowing the camera. This code executes on the P5.js web editor ( https://editor.p5js.org/ ). It looks like this :

[image]

If you want to execute the code locally, I would recommend using a Node Static Server or an editor with built-in capabilities of running a server locally. I personally use Brackets ( http://brackets.io/ ), which allows you to run HTML websites in a contained static node environment through Google Chrome. I tried executing this example on Brackets and it worked fine.